# Possible to format/create partitions with Clonezilla?

Tags: partitioning, format, clone

I am wondering if its possible to create/format/resize partitions with clonezilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with just Clonezilla, but you could use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php), a live cd that includes, among others, both Clonezilla and the Gparted partition manager.

[image: GParted]
[image: Clonezilla]

Comment: It is possible - see other answer.

Comment: Not sure if originally this was once free, but now it is offered either subscription based or one time purchase

Answer (score 7):

You can partition and format a drive if you have booted a system with a Clonezilla Live CD/DVD by obtaining a command line prompt, which is one of the menu options you will see after booting from the CD or DVD. Then use `fdisk` to partition the drive and `mkfs.ext3` to format the drive. E.g., if the drive you wish to partition and format is identified by `/dev/sdb` you could obtain a command prompt and issue the fdisk command below to create a new partition on the drive.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

You could then partition the drive within fdisk. After partitioning the drive you could format partition 1 on the drive with the ext3 file system with the command below:

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

Or you could substitute another file system type for ext3, e.g., ext2, ext4, msdos, ntfs, vfat.

E.g., see [Partitioning and formatting a disk drive with Clonezilla](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/Clonezilla/partition-format.php).

If you wish to resize a drive formatted with the [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) file system, you can use the [ntfsresize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfsresize) command.

When you have finished with the drive changes, you can get back to the Clonezilla menus with `sudo clonezilla`

Comment: That is "upgrade clonezilla". Somewhere between 1.2.6 and 2.4.2 fdisk was added to clonezilla.